# Vim color scheme does not work in tmux

Tags: terminal, vim, colors, tmux, konsole

I am using `konsole-4.14.3`, `tmux-2.6`, `vim-7.4.1938` and my shell is bash. Outside tmux, my vim color scheme works properly. However, inside tmux the colors are completely different. I kind of know what the problem is, but not sure how to solve it.

The default `$TERM` value for my terminal is `xterm`. If I add

```
set -g default-terminal screen-256color
set -g terminal-overrides ',screen-256color:Tc'
```

to my `~/.tmux.conf` and `export TERM=screen-256color` to my `~/.bashrc`, vim colors work properly in tmux. However, changing the value of `TERM` makes line wrapping to stop working both outside and inside tmux.

How should I fix this?

Comment: `TERM=xterm` describes a terminal supporting 8 (16) colors, whereas `TERM=screen-256color` describes one with 256-color support. No wonder `vim` picks a different color scheme upon seeing different terminal capabilities. Since you prefer the one inside tmux, why not set `TERM=xterm-256color` outside (directly in `konsole`; I believe this is also the default of newer `konsole` versions), and of course leave `TERM=screen-256color` inside `tmux` as you already have it.

Answer (score 4):

I found a fix. I removed the lines in `~/.tmux.conf` that set the terminal to `screen-256color` so that `tmux` chooses the default. I did NOT change `$TERM` in my `~/.bashrc` or anywhere else. Then I started tmux with `tmux -2` which forces tmux to use 256 colors. Make sure to source your conf with `:source-file ~/.tmux.conf` and to restart your terminal. Manually setting tmux to `screen-256color` or `xterm-256color` did not work for me as it caused line-wrapping to stop working. Note that although my default `$TERM` value was `xterm`, konsole would still support 256 colors.

Comment: Works really well

Comment: thanks, this really helped